# Replacing bind-attr with ternary operator by HTMLBars-style bound attribute

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am at a Ember.JS 2.0 upgrade and don't know how to replace bind-attr with ternary operator by HTMLBars-style bound attribute:

```
<li {{bind-attr class="currentPage.isCurrent:active"}}>
```

This does not set the active class if isCurrent is true:

```
<li class="{{currentPage.isCurrent:active}}">
```

As a workaround I use if and else which results in bad code duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that `active` a variable on currentPage? I think either this:

```
{{if currentPage.isCurrent currentPage.active}}
```

Or this;

```
{{if currentPage.isCurrent 'active'}}
```

would work.